# Why BIND does not use the forwarders any more?

Tags: domain-name-system, debian, bind

BIND does not use the forwarders to resolve any more. It just goes to the root servers. I do not know when this started happening since everything worked transparently, but for sure bind configuration was not altered. It was upgraded though using apt.

I am on Debian 7 and current bind version is BIND 9.8.4.

Configuration:

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";
    forwarders { 
        8.8.8.8;
        8.8.4.4;
    };
    forward only;
    dnssec-validation no;
    auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

Any ideas to re enable forwarding?

Comment: Can you try adding `allow-recursion { any; };` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but for sure bind configuration was not altered. It was upgraded
>   though using apt.

Upgrading the core engine is enough to make things not working, even if the configuration has not been altered !

As mentioned [here](https://kb.isc.org/article/AA-00269/0/What-has-changed-in-the-behavior-of-allow-recursion-and-allow-query-cache.html) :

> In versions of BIND prior to (and including) BIND 9.4.1, the default
>   behavior of BIND servers was to allow recursion for all clients
>   (unless otherwise specified.)

So you should explicitely allow recursion because it is needed to make Forwarders work :

```
allow-recursion { any; };
```

---

To retain the same behaviour you have previously i would suggest to add these directives into your `options { ... }` block :

```
allow-recursion { any; };
allow-query { any; };
allow-query-cache { any; };
```

Comment: Added all the options suggested, still no luck. From what I see, bind always uses the root servers to resolve. Added "recursion yes" well, still no luck.

Comment: @yannisf Did you check logs to get some clues ?

Comment: Checked the logs, no hint there. I am confident that for some reason the forwarder I used so far (Norton ConnectSafe: 199.85.126.20) does not work with the above options. When I switched to OpenDNS it worked. The strange thing is that Norton ConnectSafe works when in resolv.conf (you may check it if you want).

Answer (score 1):

Forwarders only work if you have recursion enabled.

Also, you should use your ISPs DNS servers, not Google's.

Comment: Any technical reason not to use Google's DNS servers?

Comment: If there's an issue with Google's DNS, you have no legs to stand on, so to speak. If it's your ISP, at least you can call somebody and notify them of the issue, and have a chance of getting it resolved.

Comment: Valid point. :)

Comment: @VasiliSyrakis: I believe that if Google DNS fail, they will be fixed quicker than I would realize that something is wrong. They are "monitored" by half of Internet using them and probably maintained much better than my ISP's ones. YMMV.